# Understanding generic compile error

Tags: c#, generics

I have 2 abstract classes:

BasePoco:

```
public abstract class BasePoco
{
    public BasePoco(){}
  // Properties etc...
}
```

BaseViewModel:

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel<T> where T : BasePoco, new()
{
  // ViewModel stuff...
}
```

If I try something like this:

```
            var baseViewModel = currentView.DataContext as BaseViewModel<BasePoco>;
            if (baseViewModel != null)
                baseViewModel.Dispose();
```

I always get the following compiler error:

> The type 'BasePoco' must be a non-abstract type with a public
>   parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter
>   'BaseViewModel' in the generic type or method 'generic'

I don't know why, could you explain and how to fix this?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do. Does `currentView.DataContext` actually contain an instance of `BaseViewModel<BasePoco>`? It couldn't. Maybe it contains an instance of `BaseViewModel<BasePocoSubClass>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know why, could you explain

The problem is that `BaseViewModel` has a constraint on `T` that `T` can be constructed via `new T()`. Since `BasePoco` is abstract, then it cannot be constructed via `new BasePoco()`. Therefore, `BaseViewModel<BasePoco>` is not a valid type.

> how to fix this?

Since all what you are doing is disposing the object, then you can cast it to `IDisposable` like this:

```
var disposable = currentView.DataContext as IDisposable;
if (disposable != null)
    disposable.Dispose();
```

Comment: if I use your way with IDisposable, my var disposable is null after the as keyword, so it isn't an IDisposable, why?

Comment: Does `BaseViewModel` implement `IDisposable`? If not, then why are you trying to call `Dispose` on it?

Comment: Is there a method called `Dispose` that is defined in `BaseViewModel`? If so, then make `BaseViewModel` implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: you are right... Sorry for my mistake and thanks for all!

Answer (score 1):

It's because public constructor of abstract class is not fully public because you can't call it directly. One of the possible fixes is to delete new() constraint from your `ViewModel` if it's not necessary.

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel<T> where T : BasePoco
{
    // ViewModel stuff...
}
```

The other option is to have non-geric class with `Dispose()` method:

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel
{
    public void Dispose() {} // or abstract method
}

public abstract class BaseViewModel<T> : BaseViewModel 
    where T : BasePoco, new()
{
    // ViewModel stuff...
}

var baseViewModel = currentView.DataContext as BaseViewModel;
if (baseViewModel != null)
    baseViewModel.Dispose();
```

Comment: That or specify the specific derived class of `BasePoco` that isn't abstract instead.